# I try to build a universal wheel, but it rolls away

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-wheel

I run:

```
python3 setup.py bdist_wheel --universal
```

It says it's making all sorts of stuff, but then the resulting directory (build/bdist.macosx-10.10-x86_64) is empty.  Where did my wheel roll away to?t

*Edit*

I now see that I'm trying to look at the temp output. When I specify `-d`, sure enough, there's a wheel in the designated location. Does `-d` have a default? Has my wheel been parked under my nose all along?

```
running bdist_wheel
running build
running build_py
running egg_info
writing dependency_links to rosapi_launcher.egg-info/dependency_links.txt
writing top-level names to rosapi_launcher.egg-info/top_level.txt
writing rosapi_launcher.egg-info/PKG-INFO
writing requirements to rosapi_launcher.egg-info/requires.txt
reading manifest file 'rosapi_launcher.egg-info/SOURCES.txt'
writing manifest file 'rosapi_launcher.egg-info/SOURCES.txt'
installing to build/bdist.macosx-10.10-x86_64/wheel
running install
running install_lib
creating build/bdist.macosx-10.10-x86_64/wheel
creating build/bdist.macosx-10.10-x86_64/wheel/launcher
copying build/lib/launcher/__init__.py -> build/bdist.macosx-10.10-x86_64/wheel/launcher
copying build/lib/launcher/containers.py -> build/bdist.macosx-10.10-x86_64/wheel/launcher
copying build/lib/launcher/launcher.py -> build/bdist.macosx-10.10-x86_64/wheel/launcher
copying build/lib/launcher/prop_file.py -> build/bdist.macosx-10.10-x86_64/wheel/launcher
copying build/lib/launcher/properties.py -> build/bdist.macosx-10.10-x86_64/wheel/launcher
copying build/lib/launcher/snapshots.py -> build/bdist.macosx-10.10-x86_64/wheel/launcher
copying build/lib/launcher/utils.py -> build/bdist.macosx-10.10-x86_64/wheel/launcher
running install_egg_info
Copying rosapi_launcher.egg-info to build/bdist.macosx-10.10-x86_64/wheel/rosapi_launcher-0.0.1-py3.4.egg-info
running install_scripts
creating build/bdist.macosx-10.10-x86_64/wheel/rosapi_launcher-0.0.1.dist-info/WHEEL
```

My setup.py is:

```
from setuptools import setup
import io
import os
import launcher

here = os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(__file__))

# noinspection PyPackageRequirements
def read(*filenames, **kwargs):
    encoding = kwargs.get('encoding', 'utf-8')
    sep = kwargs.get('sep', '\n')
    buf = []
    for filename in filenames:
        with io.open(filename, encoding=encoding) as f:
            buf.append(f.read())
    return sep.join(buf)

long_description = read('README.txt', 'CHANGES.txt')

setup(
    name='rosapi-launcher',
    version=launcher.__version__,
    install_requires=['pyaml',
                      'boto3'
                      ],
    description='RosAPI launcher',
    long_description=long_description,
    packages=['launcher'],
    include_package_data=True,
    platforms='any',
    classifiers = [
        'Programming Language :: Python',
        'Natural Language :: English'
    ]
)
```

Comment: Nice title there! Have you been participating on meta a lot? (Tho I guess we keep such titles to meta only :-) )

Comment: I've been using small doses of humor here since 2010.

Comment: Well then I will have to stalk your profile ;) Hehe, but I guess this title would be the funniest.

Comment: Hahaha. Nice. "rolls away" someone give that man some points for wit!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer I found is this:

```
python3 setup.py bdist_wheel
```

doesn't write the results anyplace *I* can find them.

```
python3 setup.py bdist_wheel -d .
```

writes it, well, right here.

Answer (score 1):

If I got you right, you search for resulting `.whl` file in `./build/...` directory. But resulting files, both source distribution and wheel, usually by default get created in the `./dist/` directory, which is located near the `build` directory. Have you searched there?

Comment: I don't remember where I looked in November.